# Logging two-dimensional array is erratic

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, google-chrome-devtools, console.log

[image]

Could someone explain this behavior of console.log in Chrome's dev tool? If instead of logging x I return it, I get the results you'd expect. Is this simply a bug?

**EDIT:**

```
function demo() {
  var x = [[1,1],2,3]
  console.log(x)
  console.log(x)
  console.log(x[0])
  x[0] = 42
}
```

Comment: Please add your code as code.

Comment: @charlietfl I would expect console.log to display the object at the point of logging, regardless of following mutations.

Comment: console isn't a snapshot of objects...they are live objects with inheritance. Stringify  at time you log then will see difference